# Simulating $f(Ax + b)$

Tags: distributions, simulation

Let $f_1$ be the density function of the logistic distribution, and let the product density function $f(x,y,z) = f_1(x)f_1(y)f_1(z)$. A $3 \times 2$-matrix $A$ is given. Its two columns are orthogonal and each of them is normalized. A vector $b$ of length $3$ is given as well.

I want to simulate the distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose density function is, up to a normalization constant, the function $(u,v) \mapsto f\bigl(A\cdot(u,v) + b\bigr)$. What are the possible methods?

Answer (score -1):

Let $Y = A^{\dagger}(X-b)$ where $A^{\dagger}$ is the [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$. If $X\sim f(x)$, then we have $Y\sim f(Ay+b)$

Proof: let $g:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with finite support,
$$\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(A^{\dagger}(x-b)) f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(A^{-1}(Ay+b-b)) f(Ay+b)d(Ay+b)$$
Hence (this is a tricky part),
$$\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(y) f(Ay+b)|\mathrm{det}(A)|dy$$
where $\mathrm{det}(A)=\prod \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are the non-zero singular values of $A$ (using for example 3.6.2 in Measure Theory, Vol 1, by V.I. Bogachev, I think this work I am not sure, I did not do the whole computation).

Illustration:
[image]

code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import pinv

Sigma = np.diag([1, 2, 3])
X = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0,0], Sigma, size=1000)

A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,1]])
b = np.array([1,2,3])

Y = np.array([pinv(A)@(x-b) for x in X])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.hist2d(Y[:,0], Y[:,1], bins=(50, 50), cmap=plt.cm.Reds)

from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
law = multivariate_normal([0,0,0], Sigma)
xs = np.linspace(-10, 6, 50)
ys = np.linspace(-5, 7, 50)
z = np.array([ law.pdf(A@np.array([x,y]) +b ) for y in ys for x in xs])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
Z = z.reshape(50, 50)
ax2.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but $A$ is not square, hence not invertible.

Comment: Ah, good point sorry did not catch that.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I fixed it, it is trickier but still feasible.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm going to try it. Could you explain a bit what do you do in Python (I don't read Python)? Are you comparing the results obtained by your method which yield a multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, in the python code I sample according to a multivariate normal distribution in dimension 3 (sample is called X) and I construct Y as proposed with the pseudo inverse. Then, I plot a 2D histogram of Y. And then, I also plot the theoretical distribution of the normal (The axes are the same for the two figures). These are the two figures represented here. The two figures are pixelated one of them this is because of the bins of the histogram and the second it is just because I did not use enough points on which I plot the function.